# Suggestion on developing training utility

Tags: python, c++, .net, scripting, automation

We have a Vendor based Finance product that is used in Windows based systems to book trades and support front to back coverage - starting from booking trades, managing risk and generating real time documents. Internal developers can use this vendor based product,services and libraries to create new interfaces by using the APIs to facilitate some of the needs of the business partners.

We want to provide training for the new comers starting from functional to technical aspects of this product so that we can involve them in development and support.

Can we develop any interactive training utility which will reduce the manual training involvement and this training utility can be used every year for the new comers . The training utility should provide all kinds of information needed for the training. It should have something demo version through which users can interact, do some real time exercise and have a feel of the product.

Can anyone please suggest what should be the technical approach to develop this utility.

Comment: Please, clarify your question. "Can we develop any interactive training utility" Of course, why not.

Comment: I am basically looking for the technical approach to develop this utility. Any references will be helpful.

Comment: The requirements for an app are usually best set by users. They know what they need. Put yourself in their shoes. Ask somebody who knows just a bit (if he knows a lot on programming he's not a real user :) Ask things like "you prefer a menu or an assistant" "you prefer many windows at once or one by one" "you prefer typing or clicking" etc.

Comment: Yes i agree.Requirements can be set by users.But my question is how we can develop the utility technically. Is there any open framework available..or is there any options available using python or C++ languages to develop this.